# Code that is in MySQL that I wish to convert to mysqli

Tags: mysqli

Hi I have line of code that is in MySQL that I wish to convert to mysqli

```
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);
```

Does anyone know an alternative I can use for mysqli.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $result = $mysqli->query($pages_query);
  $row = $result->fetch_row() ;
  $pages = ceil($row[0] / $per_page);
```

Comment: Didn't work for me- or I couldn't get it working but thankyou anyway.

Comment: can you show your code and how you tried this code ?

Comment: I've written over it now I'm afraid- I just used a different pagination code in the end, it was probably just me being stupid!